# Response for preflight is invalid (redirect) error occur

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xmlhttprequest, cors, preflight

```
 test4 = () => {

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                var xmlDoc1 = xhr.responseText;
                console.log("?", xmlDoc1)
}
        xhr.open("GET",'http://www.naver.com');
 xhr.open("Access-Control-Allow-Origin",'http://www.naver.com');
        xhr.send();
        }
    }

componentDidMount() {
this.test4()
}
```

error ==> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.naver.com/. Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)
please help me...

Answer (score 3):

There are a few problems here.  Primarily though, [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) is preventing you from doing an XHR to www.naver.com.  Unless you have some way to tell `www.naver.com` to allow you to make these types of requests, then you can't from a browser client.

First, the `.open` method is not used to add headers to a request. Second, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a response header not a request header. It would make very little sense for the client to be able to declare the permitted access control to the server. Ref: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Simple_requests)